# When using a jupyter notebook in VSCode, the Python interpreter is ignored

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, interpreter

I have a virtual environment with some installed packages and a notebook with some imports of packages that only exist in this environment.

I have done Ctrl + Shift + P > Python: Select Interpreter, and chosen my environment.

But, if I run the cell, it tells me ModuleNotFoundError, as it tries to use my global Python environment for the imports (if I install the packages globally the cell succeeds).

Therefore, the selected Interpreter is ignored, and the global environment is always used.

I also tried using my environment in: Jupyter: Select Interpreter to Start Jupyter Server, but the result did not change.

This problem does not exist in a python file, only in the jupyter notebooks.

How to fix it? Am I forced to install packages globally when using Jupyter Notebooks?

Comment: Please provide at least the code containing the imports. At which module import does it throw the error? This problem can have many roots. First, for notebooks, you should select kernels with the `Notebook: Select Notebook Kernel` command in VSCode. Try and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For `.py` scripts

  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> Python: Select Interpreter

  [image]
- For Jupyter Notebook

  Click `Select Kernel` in the upper right corner (Or the kernel version already shown) Select `Python Environments...`.

  [image]

  [image]

***These are two different ways of choosing a python environment.***

Answer (score -1):

try anaconda software, in this software contain jupiter notebook but its doesn't contain any error to interpret python program and its interpreter is good working condition than VScode.